How to count all highlight words number by use react-pdf?
I use react-pdf to render pdf files, and one function is to count all the hightlight words number,code is like this:
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

import samplePDF from './test.pdf';

function highlightPattern(text, pattern) {
  return text.replace(pattern, (value) => `<mark>${value}</mark>`);
}

export default function Test() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  const textRenderer = useCallback(
    (textItem) => highlightPattern(textItem.str, searchText),
    [searchText]
  );

  function onChange(event) {
    setSearchText(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Document file={samplePDF}>
        <Page
          pageNumber={1}
          customTextRenderer={textRenderer}
        />
      </Document>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="search">Search:</label>
        <input type="search" id="search" value={searchText} onChange={onChange} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

It's work fine,but the customTextRenderer function don't tell me when the render is complete,so i can't use useState method,such as setNumber to update UI,what should i do?
I can use useRef to store the search result,but i can't use setState to update useRef.current's result.
